# Testing Microsoft ASP.NET Web API ---- in-memory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, in-memory

Is there guidance and examples on how to setup and structure tests, **in-memory**,  for Microsoft Web API class project which is independent of hosts (to put it simply it is not a Web API inside ASP.NET MVC project).

The Web API class library itself is boot strapped with configuration being set up via `HttpConfiguration`.

I would like to know if there is formal guidance and examples of the various tests that can be written for this setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any formal documentation available but here are two good blog posts - one by [Kiran](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/05/06/in-memory-client-amp-host-and-integration-testing-of-your-web-api-service.aspx) and the other one by [Filip](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/).